# What do lockFocus and unlockFocus actually do?

Tags: cocoa, drawing

*Warning: I'm a Cocoa newbie.*

I'm reading "Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X" by Hillegass.

On p.301 it's written:

> To make the drawing appear on the image instead of on the screen, you must first lock focus on the image. When the drawing is complete, you must unlock focus.

The code I have, inside `-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent` of an `NSView` is as follows:

```
[resizedImage lockFocus];
[sourceImage drawInRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, resizeWidth, resizeHeight) fromRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, originalSize.width, originalSize.height) operation: NSCompositeSourceOver fraction: 1.0];
[resizedImage unlockFocus];
```

Without the lock/unlock, this does not work, but I still don't understand exactly what is going on.

I see that the 2nd line of code has no mention of `resizedImage` so does that mean when I use `lockFocus` it makes sure any 'drawing' that happens takes place there? Could someone explain this better?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Drawing requires a 'graphics context'. You'll notice that, unlike Core Graphics, none of the AppKit drawing methods take a parameter that specifies where the drawing ends up. Instead, the destination is stored globally as `[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]`. All AppKit drawing methods affect this current context.

The main purpose of `-lockFocus` (on images and views alike) is to set up the graphics context so your drawing ends up going where you want it to.

Comment: Worth noting that these stack, so, for example, it's safe to do this in a view's `drawRect:` (which runs in between `lockFocus` and `unlockFocus` to the view).

Comment: Peter, What do you mean by do this?

Answer (score 6):

From the docs for `-[NSImage lockFocus]`:

> This method sets the current drawing context to the area of the offscreen window used to cache the receiver's contents.

So there exists an offscreen window which you draw on when you draw to the image. This image has a graphics context and `lockFocus` makes this context the current drawing context so that `drawInRect:...` uses it for its drawing. It's similar to `+[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext]`.